# Правильная установка кодировки при выводе из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сама БД в кодировке utf-8
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пытаюсь вывести на страницу 
Вот сам код

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$db_hostname = "localhost";
$db_database = "cms";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
    if($connection-> connect_error) die($connection -> connect_error);
$query = "SELECT * FROM category";
$result = $connection -> query($query);
    if(!$result) die($connection -> connect_error);
for($i = 0, $lenght = $result -> num_rows; $i < $lenght;$i++){
    $result -> data_seek($i);
    $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['title']."<br>";
}
$result -> close();
```

Всем заранее благодарю за ответ :)

Comment: кодировка файла самого?

Comment: utf-8 стоит в файле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу после подключения к базе вставляю функцию

```
$connection->set_charset("utf8");
```

Всем благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Если такое возникает, значит где-то есть некорректная кодировка. Все данные должны быть в одной кодировке. И файл со скриптом, и данные в таблице БД и отправляемые заголовки браузеру с указанием кодировки( если есть ).

По вашему вопросу нельзя определить кодировку заголовков, так что ограничусь ссылкой с подробными объяснениями: http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-database/thread198468.html

Плюс к этому, поскольку из вопроса неясны настройки веб-сервера, попробуйте добавить в .htaccess строку `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`.

Comment: 1.Есть header с utf-8
2.Сохранил в кодировке utf-8(без BOM)
3.поставил set_charset("utf8")
4.Сама база в utf-8
В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: А если в базу зайти через phpmyadmin - там все корректно, все слова видятся как надо?

Comment: да,все корректно,нашел ошибку,спасибо за помощь)